# protecting a hard drive with confidential information

Tags: hard-drive, encryption

I am about to give a hard drive with many pdfs that contain information and high-res photographs to someone in an institution and would like to limit the possibility of those photographs being seen by anyone else or copied. If possible I would like people to not be able to print them either.
I understand that ultimately it might not be possible to stop them being copied but I d like to make it as hard as possible for someone to get hold of the hard drive and copy it.

Comment: Make them sign a legally binding agreement. I'm not sure there's a technical solution to this as you're, in effect, giving them the data.

Comment: That would not counter any theft.

Comment: Put the files in a zip file protected with password. Only a brute force attack could open the zip file.

Comment: Right, legally binding agreement provides recourse but doesn't stop theft or unwanted actions such as disseminating the contents of the drive. As you expand the chain of custody you increase risk. You can also require the recipient has an appropriate government clearance such as a Public Trust, Secret, or Top Secret.

Comment: The best way to ensure that only the right eyes see the files, is requiring the user(s) to travel to your location so you control the environment. They want to see the documents, they make an appointment, come over, and view them. No access to copying them or anything.

Comment: Give them a different hard drive that only contains information you want them to see, encrypt it in case it is stolen.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is use a program like Winzip or 7zip and create an archive with these files and password protect them. If you don't want to hand out the filenames either, place all files in a folder first and archive the entire folder with a password.

Upon opening the archive, it will show the root (just one folder) and asks for the password. The user has to enter the correct password or abort, and only after entering the right password, will they be able to see the filenames and open the files.

Keep in mind, whenever someone has access to the files, no matter what, they can make them accessible to anyone. But those who work with confidential files will know that risk. You should make a disclaimer stating that, once they receive the files you are no longer responsible for what happens to it.

Comment: This doesn't prevent a third-party from accessing the files.  There isn't a good solution to this problem otherwise we would not have people like Snowden

Comment: @Ramhound it makes it harder, which is what OP asks.

Comment: You can't protect somebody from removing the password on that archive.   Protecting digital files from theft is a problem that has not been solved.

Answer (score 1):

Encrypt and password protect everything you can than do as Joe Taylor said.

Start with [BitLocker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BitLocker) to encrypt the HDD in case of theft.

PDF can also be protected. Just follow [these](http://www.digitaltrends.com/computing/password-protect-pdf/) steps. You can disable printing as well. Of course this is not 100% secure but it would cause some headache for someone to steal the data.

You can't do too much about the photos but to put them into a pdf or MS Word, etc. You have to use a third party software if this is an option.

You can zip them as well since you can password protect a zip file.

For the passwords use at least 8 characters and make sure to have at least 3 out of these variations: `lower case, higher case, number, special character`

Comment: PDF documents have the added benefit of having a setting that prevent copies from being saved ( i.e. save as not copy and paste ) and prevent printing.  Encrypting the individual document using EFS and making sure the terminal doesn't allow mass storage devices and optical disk drives are addtional ways.